# Matlab's binoinv equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, statistics, data-analysis

Is there a Python equivalent of the `binoinv` Matlab function? I am new to data analysis and don't have much experience in this domain. It would really be very helpful if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that functionality in [`scipy.stats.binom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html):

- Matlab:

  ```
  >> x = binoinv([.3 .7 .9], 100, .25)
  ans =
      23    27    31
  ```
- Python:

  ```
  >>> from scipy.stats import binom
  >>> x = binom.ppf([.3, .7, .9], 100, .25)
  >>> print(x)
  [ 23.  27.  31.]
  ```